# Unit test - read xml file

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I m trying to do a unit test to a class which load and read an xml file.
I m using NetBeans.

Here is my class structure,

```
Class A
{

private String fileName;

A (String fileName)
 {
  this.fileName = fileName;
  load();
 }
private load()
{
//here i load a xml file by given name
} 
public readXml()
{
// read xml file and return list of records
}
}
```

Using NetBeans, it generates me some test classes with methods

```
  @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }
 @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }
 @Before
    public void setUp() {
}
```

and one method which TestReadXml()

where i have to load the file in order to perform unit testing of method "readXml", because for that clas "A" i hava method "load()" which is called in the cunstrctor in order to load the file and method readXml is use only for reading and returning records.

Thanks

Edit

want to test method readXml(), give a expect result which is in the input xml file.
the preriquest is to load a xml file.
The point is that i dont know where to do this action, so i get an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.schober.main.ATest.testReadXml(ATest.java:83)
```

because here
 assertEquals(expResult, result);

the result is null

Comment: What is your question? How to read a file? How to parse XML?

Comment: i want to know how to perform unit-test when i have a prerequisite (file must be loaded first) because the method i want to test only read an xml (no loading there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test all public methods and constructors of a class file. The tests will verify, that every call with every possible input gives the *expected* result.

In your case, you could write some tests to test the constructor. Call it with different parameters like

- A String that represents a readable and valid xml file
- `null`
- A String that does not represent a file or folder
- A String that represents a folder
- A String that represents a file which does not contain xml code
- A String that represents a file that contains malformed xml code
- A String that represents a file that contains invalid xml code
- A String that represents a file that contains valid xml code but uses a different schema

Comment: Shouldn't a unit test avoid dependencies like the file system?  It's my (limited) understanding that you should mock that kind of interaction, although I got here looking for a question that explains how to mock the layers of interactions from input string -> file system -> file contents -> valid xml schema -> valid xml data.